# binding packages with wxpython

Tags: python, data-binding, wxpython, package

I'm kind of new with wxpython and python itself, sorry for the basic question.

I'm trying to organize my code in a more easy way to manage it. I created this simple example that kind of resume my problem. Basically it is just a window with a button that print a message. I separated it in three simple packages

ef_Main.py - This is the main packages it will import the UI and the application itself.

ef_Tool.py - it is the application that will run all the important code, right now it is just a print statment but will have all the application code.

ef_UI.py - a very basic interface using wxpython.

How it should work:

Run ef_Main.py it will import the interface (ef_UI.py) and the main code (ef_Tool.py). When something is click in the interface it will be ready by the ef_Main and send to ef_Tool to be executed.

My problem is:

I'm not sure how to use bind function to connect this three packages. I believe that it should be in the ef_Main but how it will get the info from the interface and send it to the ef_Tool.py.

And if I want to get some output from the ef_Tool and send it back to the interface. How should I do that.

Here is my code.

```
#ef_Main.py

import wx
import ef_UI as eU
import ef_Tool as eT


''' Here is where I don't know how to make it works,
if I should put a class here or not, and how to bind
this function with the impTool and impUI'''

#class MyMain(self):
def uiControls(self):
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, eU.OnClick(self), eT.MyTools(self))


def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = eU.MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

=======================

```
#ef_Tool.py

import wx

'''just a simple as possible function to be execute when it is called '''
class MyTools():
    def OnClick(self, event):
        #Value = self.MyTextCtrl.GetValue()
        print "it is working! "
```

=======================

```
#ef_UI.py

import wx

''' very simple interface with only a button and a TextCtrl '''
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Menu Test")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.MyButton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Button_test", (0, 0))
        self.MyTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value="just a test", pos=(100, 0))
```

Thanks in advance!

Emerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of fulfilling your requirements. Supposing all your application logic is done in `ef_Tool.py` and the input for these logic is from `ef_UI` and the output is also sent to `ef_UI.py`.

You need to call a method in `ef_Tool.py` when a button click event occurs in `ef_UI`. You can invoke this method from `MyFrame`'s method. But you need an obj of `MyTools` to do this.

so first, create an obj for `MyTools` in `ef_Main.py` and pass this object to `MyFrame`

```
#ef_Main.py

import wx
import  ef_UI as eU
import ef_Tool as eT


def main():
    efToolObj = eT.MyTools() # object of MyTools class
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = eU.MyFrame(efToolObj) # Pass this to MyFrame so that it can make use of it
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Store this `MyTools`'s object in you MyFrame class. And then use this object to call the corresponding method inside `MyTools`

```
#ef_UI.py

import wx

''' very simple interface with only a button and a TextCtrl '''
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, efToolObj):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Menu Test")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.efToolObj = efToolObj # save the MyTools object to be used later
        self.MyButton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Button_test", (0, 0))
        self.MyButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClickEvent) # Bind the click event to an event handling method
        self.MyTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value="just a test", pos=(100, 0))


    def onClickEvent(self,event): #this is called when a button is clicked
        res = self.efToolObj.OnClickPrinting(self.MyTextCtrl.GetValue()) #Use the mytools object to call its method to apply logic,also get result values
        self.MyTextCtrl.SetValue(res) #use the result values in your UI
```

You can pass the info you want to send to the application logic in its arguments and get results as return values.

```
#ef_Tool.py

class MyTools:
    def OnClickPrinting(self,textvalue):
        #Value = self.MyTextCtrl.GetValue()
        print "it is working! ",textvalue 

        resultstr = "test successful"
        return resultstr
```

Hope this helped.